# Slugify not saving title as slug Django 2: NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Can't seem to get the `slug` field to save because I am getting the error `NoReverseMatch`.

```
Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '(5, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blogpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$']
```

Could someone look over my code please as I am having trouble finding the problem?

urls.py

```
path('blogpost/<int:pk>/<str:slug>', news_views.BlogPostDetailView.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=190, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=190, editable=False, unique=True, blank=True, default='')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            kwargs = {
                'pk': self.pk,
                'slug': self.slug,
            }
            return reverse('blog_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class BlogPostDetailView(DetailView):
    context = {
        'blog': BlogPost.objects.all(),
    }
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/blog_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
```

homepage.html

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_detail' blog.pk blog.slug %}">{{ blog.title }}</a>
```

Comment: Is the indentation on your models.py as it is in your project, or is it messed up here? If it matches, then it's wrong - your `save` and `get_absolute_url` methods need to be indented ... That would explain why your slug is empty at least.

Comment: BTW, I slugify both the text and the pk into the same field, which avoids the need to reference 2 keys ... eg. `self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title} {str(self.id)}")`

Comment: Hey I've fixed it, no it was messed up on here.

Comment: I just tried changing to `self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title} {str(self.id)}")` and changing the url to `href="{% url 'blog_detail' blog.slug %}"` but now the pk isn't found

Comment: That's because you probably still have the pk specified in the `urls.py` file. If you have them both in the slug you don't need that - your url only needs to contain the slug (which in itself contains both the text and the pk, ensuring it is unique)

Comment: Also, you can't just change the code and expect that to work on existing data - you'd have to migrate the old data first as well, or just clear it out and start again.

Comment: I had removed `pk` from urls.py and created a new instance but I had to remove the `/` and replace it with `-` in urls.py so it read `blogpost/<int:pk>-<str:slug>'` for it to work in the admin panel `view on site`. However on the homepage I still get `Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '('this-is-a-blog-6',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blogpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\-(?P<slug>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: If you set the slug to include the pk though, you don't need that at all in the `urls.py`, so you can just have `blogpost/<str:slug>'/` - the slug includes the pk. Do note my comment about existing data though (If you can re-save every record though, the `save` method should recalculate the slug value so it's correct).

Comment: Ah! Sorry, totally forgot to remove `'pk': self.pk` from the kwargs

Comment: I've just noticed your problem I think :) You use `<str:slug>` in `urls.py`. It should be `<slug:slug>` - it's not a string type. Perhaps that should work anyway since python doesn't have strong typing, but  I would correct it anwyay ...

Comment: Remove it from the url dispatcher as well :)

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help!! Yes, I've removed it from the url dispatcher :) If you add your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: And `<str:slug>` seems to work, what is the benefit of using `<slug:slug>`? I had `<slug:slug>` at one point but changed it back to str

Comment: I think `<slug:slug>` is just the standard for this type of field, and therefore more Pythonic :) My suspicion is that `str` works because Python doesn't do strong typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both the text and the pk into a single slug, and then simply reference that.

In the save method:

```
self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title} {str(self.id)}")
```

This also means that your slug will always be unique, because it includes the pk.

Then in urls.py set the path as:

```
'blogpost/<slug:slug>'
```

You won't need to pass `pk` in the `kwargs` any more then, but do note that existing data won't be magically fixed by this - if you re-save each record though the revised `save` method should sort them out. You can also remove the pk reference from the template, as all you will need to pass now is the slug.